# Satoshi's final statement

Tags: history, satoshi-nakamoto, email

I read some articles about Satoshi's history and stumbled upon this one:

> No one knows what Satoshi is up to, but one of the last emails he sent to a software developer, dated April 23 2011, said “I’ve moved on to other things. It’s in good hands with Gavin and everyone.”

Source: http://www.coindesk.com/information/who-is-satoshi-nakamoto/

This sentence of Satoshi is quoted many times in the web, but I can't find a source who published it or to which developer it was send. I know there are archives of Satoshi's mails but I didn't find this statement in any of them.

Does anybody have further information about it?

Comment: Actually his latest statement was about him not being Dorian Nakamoto earlier this year: http://p2pfoundation.ning.com/forum/topics/bitcoin-open-source?commentId=2003008%3AComment%3A52186

Comment: yeah I saw this one, but I'm not sure if this is a real post of him, because its a different account than the original one, still it uses the same email

Comment: I remember the owner of p2pfoundation was able to verify his signature. Can't find reference of this though.

Comment: Who is gavin here

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've got [an answer on Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/29bamh/source_of_satoshis_final_statement/cij9m83):

It's likely to have been written in a [PM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_message) or an email to some developers, and it seems that Mike Hearn (BitcoinJ) was the one who published this statement:

> Mike Hearn - February 25, 2013, 12:48:54 PM
>
> He communicated with a few of the core developers before leaving. He
>   told myself and Gavin that he had moved on to other things and that
>   the project was in good hands.

Source: *[Re: Could Satoshi come back and tell us what he/her thinks about the block size?](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=145850.msg1558053#msg1558053)*

Still, if someone has additional information I would be glad to know about.

Answer (score 6):

Ultimate necro, but it was Mike Hearn. You can find multiple emails between Satoshi Nakamoto and himself from back then at his site here: http://plan99.net/%7Emike/

The specific quote you've found is the last email in the last thread (http://plan99.net/%7Emike/satoshi-emails/thread5.html).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This gives the context and conversation that email was sent in.